# Android : File cannot open after writing

Tags: android

I tried to write an image from asset to sd card. It got out but I can't open it. Is there any mistake I have done in writing it?

Here's my onBackground() code

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "myDownloadedImage.jpg");
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    AssetManager asset = context1.getAssets();


    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        Log.v("test", "File Created");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        InputStream test= asset.open("image.JPG");
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(test, 1024);

        Log.v("test", "InputStream Created");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        is.read(buffer);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read;
        long total = 0;
        Log.v("test", "OutputStream Created");
        while ((read = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            total += read;
            os.write(buffer, 0, read);
            publishProgress((int)((total*100)/2000));
        }

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also, please by any chance tell me what I should put at publishProgress()

EDIT: I checked the properties of the file outputted it said
Type : File
Path: /sdcard/
Size : 2.06 MB

Comment: do you have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION in the manifest?

Comment: @blackbelt yes, I have both WRITE and READ permissions

Comment: try to debug your application and look at the closing block. maybe your stream is not closed properly